# What does `Vec<T>` mean?

Tags: rust

[The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/dining-philosophers.html) sometimes says things like "here we want a `Vec<T>`".

Does this mean anything other than "a thing of type Vector?" Also, how would you pronounce it - "vec tee"?

Comment: Ah - [the docs say](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/) it's "written Vec<T> but pronounced 'vector.'"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Vec<T>` means "A vector of items. The items are of type `T`". Let's unpack that a bit...

A *vector* is a data structure that contains zero-or-more items of the same type. The items have an order, and you can access the items by index (0, 1, ...). You can add and remove items. The items themselves are stored in a contiguous heap-allocated area.

`T` is a common *generic type parameter*. A type parameter allows you to write code that abstracts over a specific type, without caring what that type is. In this example, we can create a `MyThing` with **any kind** of inner value:

```
struct MyThing<T> {
    thing: T,
}
```

Here, `T` is a type parameter, as it is enclosed in the `<>`. It doesn't have to be a `T`, it could be `S` or `Z` or `MyLittlePony`. However, it's common to use `T` as a shorthand for "type". It's also common to use single-letter names to avoid clashing with concrete type names.

As humans, we will sometimes be a little fast-and-loose with terminology and use `T` in the same way we might use `x` in mathematics or `foo` in programming - a thing we don't care to specify yet.

I would pronounce it aloud as "vec tee" or "a vec of tee", but this is pretty subjective.

Comment: I feel like we need a T-shirt with `Vec<` on one side and `>` on the other.

Comment: @DK. Nice. :) Or we could just print `Vec<_>` on the front.

Comment: The answer has help me understand Rust better. Thanks. I feel good, before now, i felt lost :)

Answer (score 2):

`Vec<T>` is a generic type indicating a vector where each element has type `T`. See the sections on [vectors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/vectors.html) and [generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/generics.html) for more details.