# What is the default type of `Vec::new()` in rust?

Tags: vector, rust

I'm new to Rust. I understand that Rust predicts the type of bindings at compile time. The below code compiles and runs.

```
fn main() {
    let mut numbers = Vec::new();
    numbers.push(1);
}
```

What is the default type of the `numbers` vector?

Comment: [No, it doesn't](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e4a658f8f1f93d753c310f9aa98b11eb&version=stable).

Comment: I'm very interested to know what compiler you're using and/or what you define as "compiles and runs".

Comment: I meant `rustc` and I'm using cargo.

Comment: There is no default typing in the edited post. It's `Vec<u64>`, you can tell because you're calling `u64::from_string` which is a `Result<u64,_>`, and `expect` which unwraps that value.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate of *something*, but I added an answer because I wasn't sure if this could truly be called a duplicate of the "default int literal type" problem linked in my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the {integer} in a compiler error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996784/what-is-the-integer-in-a-compiler-error-message)

Comment: @E_net4 the original question was unrelated to integers (and without apparent duplicates), but I think the asker got discouraged by the comments; I don't know how to treat this question now, though.

Comment: @ljedrz Perhaps there could be a better duplicate target, all right. But let's put things this way: the question has already been answered, new answers are unlikely to add more value, and the duplicate completes the missing knowledge (the best answer there says that `i32` is the default integral type). There is nothing to be discouraged by, and the outcome turned out more positive than it could have been for a question which had its MCVE changed multiple times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Vec::new()` relies on its context for information. When you push something to the vector, the compiler knows "oh, this is the kind of object I should be expecting". But since your example is pushing the integer literal `1`, this appears to be related to [the default type of an integer literal.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996784/what-is-the-integer-in-a-compiler-error-message/41996902#41996902)

In Rust, an untyped integer literal will be assigned a value at compile time according to the context. For example:

```
let a = 1u8;
let b = 2;
let c = a + b;
```

`b` and `c` will be `u8`s; `a + b` assigns `b` to be the same type as `a`, and the output of the operation is a `u8` as a result.

If no type is specified, the compiler appears to pick `i32` (per [this playground experiment](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=821d099623bb6f36dd1aafcf08835ec3&version=nightly)). So in your specific example, and as seen in the playground, `numbers` would be a `Vec<i32>`.

Comment: This line makes the context very clear " When you push something to the vector, the compiler knows "oh, this is the kind of object I should be expecting". very precise answer.

Answer (score 9):

Vectors in Rust are generic, which means that they don't have a default type - unless by default you mean [`Vec<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399780/what-does-vect-mean) (`T` is a generic type parameter) or [`Vec<_>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363984/what-is-vec/34364132) (`_` is a [type placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033804/what-is-the-correct-term-for-in-a-type-hint)).

If the compiler doesn't find any related type annotation or isn't able to infer the element type using type inference, it will refuse to build the code:

```
let mut numbers = Vec::new();

error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:2:23
  |
2 |     let mut numbers = Vec::new();
  |         -----------   ^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `T`
  |         |
  |         consider giving `numbers` a type
```

You can verify it further by trying to use [a trick to find out the type of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747136/how-do-i-print-the-type-of-a-variable-in-rust/21747400#21747400):

```
let mut numbers = Vec::new();
let () = numbers;

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
3 |     let () = numbers;
  |         ^^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found ()
  |
  = note: expected type `std::vec::Vec<_>` // Vec<_>
             found type `()`
```